# How to access http server directory from a java application?

Tags: java, file, httpclient

I want to access a file stored under a http directory for ex: http://www.zen134237.zen.co.uk/
from a java application. Assume the server allows directory listing or it is on FTP. could some one point me in right direction ?

Comment: There exist ready to use http clients. Did you try to use one of these? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089394/java-httpclient-how-to-download-all-the-files-from-a-given-folder?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you want to access a file under the http directory. Do you know the location of this file? You can use Java's net package and open a url connection. Then extract the contents from this url connection.

Taken from the java tutorials:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous examples on the web, so I'll just leave two pointers here:

- [Writing an FTP Client](https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CJCOOK/Writing+an+FTP+Client)
- [Apache HttpClient - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html)